# Redirect back to previous jsp page with previous form value from servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

So basically I using following code as a search parcel function, it has 2 button `addnew` and `search`
where both will get the value `target` entered in the input field, and redirected depending on which button is chose

```
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <form id="forms" method="post" action="admin_tracking.jsp">
                <input name="target" type="input" placeholder = "TrackingNo..." class = "text_search"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            function submit(value)
            {
                console.log(value)
                if (value == "add") {
                    //change action of form
                    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_tracking.jsp?status='
                    document.getElementById('forms').submit(); //submit
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_home_result.jsp'
                    document.getElementById('forms').submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <button class="button_search" value = "add" onclick="submit(this.value)">
            Add New
        </button>
        <button class="button_search" value = "srch" onclick="submit(this.value)">
            Search
        </button>
```

Once redirected to the search page, parcel with match `trackingNo` will be return and user can choose to update the status of the parcel or delete it.
When user choose to update the parcel, `AdminCollectServlet`will be call as followed:

```
href="AdminCollectServlet?target=<%=rs.getString("trackingNo")%>&from=${pageContext.request.requestURI}&query=${pageContext.request.queryString}"
```

to perform database update. Once completed i used the line

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("from") + "?" + request.getParameter("query"));
```

to redirect back to where the servlet is called.

But because the `target` was submitted in form and not as a parameter at the url, redirected page won't be able to return the search result.

I was wondering is there a way to retrieve the full form content and passed it into the `response.sendredirect()` like how the parameter can be pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store value at `client-side` you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the value of `token` before submitting the `form` and onload of page again you can get that value `localStorage.getItem(yourvalue);`.Some of the changes you need to make in your `js` and `html` code .
In your `html` code add `onload` under `body` tag .i.e :

```
 //add onload event
 <body onload="check_storage()">
 <!--other html codes-->
 </body>
```

Your `javascript` code :

```
//onload of your page this will get called
function check_storage() {
  //check if there is any value in localStorage
  if (localStorage.getItem("save") != null) {
    //get that value
    var value = localStorage.getItem("save");
    alert(value);
    //put that value again in input box
  document.getElementsByName("target")[0].value = value;
  }
}

function submit(value) {
//getting input value
  var save =  document.getElementsByName("target")[0].value;
   console.log(save);
  localStorage.clear();//clear previous data
  localStorage.setItem("save", save);//add data to storage
  if (value == "add") {
    //change action of form
    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_tracking.jsp?status='
    document.getElementById('forms').submit(); //submit
  } else {
    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_home_result.jsp'
    document.getElementById('forms').submit();
  }
}
```

Or if you need to store value at `server side` you can use [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and using [setAttribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) you store the value of `token` and get it in your jsp page simply writing `${sessionScope.yourvariablename}` .

Comment: Hey @Swati, thanks again for the help, appreciate it. I modified some part of it so that i can access javascript variable from java as below

Answer (score 0):

After going through the answer Swati mentioned above, I was able to solve part of it.
It solve the problem of getting value of `target` from my `forms` after redirected back from my `AdminCollectServlet`

But since i needed to use the the value of `target`, which is in javascript, in java to execute sql query, i modified some part.

```
        <script>
            function submit(value)
            {
                console.log(value)
                if (value == "add") {
                    //change action of form
                    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_tracking.jsp?status='
                    document.getElementById('forms').submit(); //submit
                } else {
                    var save = document.getElementById('forms')[0].value;
                    localStorage.clear();
                    localStorage.setItem("save", save);
                    localStorage.setItem("counter", "0");
                    document.getElementById('forms').action = 'admin_home_result.jsp'
                    document.getElementById('forms').submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

in my `submit(value)` function, i use as guided by Swati, adding another variable `counter`.
This variable allows me to implement the `check_storage()` function as Swati wrote above and put the `target`value in the url parameter, so that i can use it in java sql query.

```
            function check_storage()
            {
                if(localStorage.getItem("save") != null)
                {
                    var value = localStorage.getItem("save");
                    if(localStorage.getItem("counter") != null && localStorage.getItem("counter")=="0")
                    {
                        localStorage.setItem("counter", "1");
                        window.location.replace("admin_home_result.jsp?target=" + value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I used the line:

```
window.location.replace("admin_home_result.jsp?target=" + value);
```

To refresh the page with the parameter value set and the line:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("counter") != null && localStorage.getItem("counter")=="0")
```

To prevent a infinite refresh, by changing the `counter` variable before changing the url

This way allows me to store the `target` value from `forms`, redirect it to servlet, again redirect back to the original page and access javascript variable in java for my sql query